# How to slice a List into two and append the second list to the first in dart?

Tags: dart

I have a list, something like this

```
List<String> someList = ['A','B','C','D','E','F']
```

I want to slice and append it so that it'll look like this

```
someList = ['D','E','F','A','B','C']
```

Comment: `someList = someList.sublist(3) + someList.sublist(0, 3);`

Comment: Or `someList = [...someList.skip(3), ...someList.take(3)];`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basic way to slice and append to a list in dart:

```
List<String> list1 = ['hello', 'world', 'apple', 'orange'];
List<String> list2 = ['bye', 'good', 'bad', 'intention'];

list2 = list2 + list1.sublist(2,4);
print(list2); // outputs: [bye, good, bad, intention, apple, orange]
```

Thus in your case, you are just re-arranging your existing list which might look like:

```
someList = someList.sublist(3) + someList.sublist(0, 3);
```

PS this is also in the comments but for the sake of completeness I put it here too.